# Reference.vb file displaying multiple errors when a WCF service is added to the application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wcf, web-reference

I have created a vb.net application in VS2010 and **added a service as a reference but when I built the app, reference.vb is throwing multiple errors.**

**"This is the error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"**

However the same is running fine when I created a c# windows forms application.

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form:=**System**.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>  _
    Public Property MESSAGE_V4() As String
        Get
            Return Me.mESSAGE_V4Field
        End Get
        Set
            Me.mESSAGE_V4Field = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

**The references are already there so I am not sure where the issue is.**

This is something new to me as I have never seen this issue before and could not find much help on Google as well. If anyone could help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally after work around I found solution. It was easy from my end.

Just removed "**=System.**" from reference.vb and application is running smooth.

From:

```
Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)
```

To:

```
Form:=Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)
```

Thanks.